# Firebase/Flutter - App Attest Debug Token not working on Simulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check, ios-app-attest

I'm having an issue with App Attest and Firebase. I'm having my flutter app and tried to enable App Attest. Therefor I did what the documentation was saying:

1. Set up firebase project
2. Add the App check library to the app
3. Initialize app check.

After that I enforced App Check in Firebase. App Attest and accessing the data does work if I publish to real device.

No I'm having the issue when using an simulator. I know, that I have to do some things to get it working on the simulator:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider:

1. Activate App Check with debug provider

```
if (!kDebugMode) {
    await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
      appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
    );
  } else {
    print("Debug Mode");
    try {
      await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
          androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
          appleProvider: AppleProvider.debug);
     
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {

      print("FirebaseException:" + e.toString());
    }
  }
```

2. Enable debug logging in Xcode

[Enable debug logging in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuwIb.png)

3. Get the local debug token from the debug output.

[Get the local debug token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8AQe.png)

4. In Firebase add the debug token to the registered debug tokens.

[Add debug token to firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeeBZ.png)

Unfortunately here starts the problem. After doing all this stuff, I cannot access the firestore  data in the app through the simulator (android does work, iOS not). It keeps saying me, that I don't have the permissions:
"[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation."

DB-Rules should not be a problem, as they are not if I use a real device or I disable app Attest.

Additional info:

-) I changed app-attest-environment from "development" to "production"

[app-attest-environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4rYT.png)

-) Added appAttest capability in Xcode

Any ideas, what the hell is the problem?